# How insert into Text cell chevron symbols used for Inline GroupOpener icons?

Tags: cells, named-characters

If in OptionInspector I select option "Inline" for Cell Options > Display Options > ShowGroupOpener for section-like cells, then when such a group is closed it shows an icon that is a little box, with rounded corners, containing a symbol similar to a right-pointing chevron, like this:

[image: Group closed icon]

And when the group is open, the icon changes to one where the chevron points downward, like this:

[image: Group open icon]

(Ignore the color there: that's an artifact of a particular stylesheet I'm using.)

I want to be able to explain those icons in a Text cell. How can I insert those symbols there?

The best I've been able to obtain so far is the following:

```
openerClosedIcon = Framed[
  Style["\[VeryThinSpace]\[VeryThinSpace]\[VeryThinSpace]»\
    \[VeryThinSpace]\[VeryThinSpace]", Bold, 24],
  FrameMargins -> None, RoundingRadius -> 5]
```

and

```
openerOpenIcon = Rotate[openerClosedIcon, -90 Degree]
```

which produce

[image: My GroupClosedIcon]

and

[image: My GroupOpenIcon]

respectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those symbols are in fact special characters:

```
Row@{"\:f442", "\:f443"}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you find these? I did not see them on the Special Characters palette.

Comment: I didn't find them, either, in the Documentation Center page guide/SpecialCharacters.

Comment: @murray I found them by noticing that the front-end access the file `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources", "MiscExpressions.tr"}` when first displaying the symbols. And luckily, the relevant definitions for `"cellGroupOpenerInline"` are at the very top