# Symbols for some icons

Tags: front-end

What are the characters that give each of the following icons:

1. The "i" information icon you see in the predictive interface and in the output box produced by an information request (e.g., from `Plot`)?
2. The icon similar to `>` used as a group opener of sections and subsections of Documentation Center pages?

(This question is a continuation of [How insert into Text cell chevron symbols used for Inline GroupOpener icons?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249632/how-insert-into-text-cell-chevron-symbols-used-for-inline-groupopener-icons) .)

Comment: The `>` isn't a character. It is `Graphics[{
        Thickness[0.18], 
        RGBColor[0.8509803921568627, 0.396078431372549, 0], 
        Line[{{-1.8, 0.5}, {0, 0}, {1.8, 0.5}}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-3, 4}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 
       20]` and is rotated via `Dynamic` and `TaggingRules` on the NB. The `i` icon is I think also `Graphics` if I remember correctly from digging into `FrontEndResource`

Comment: Yeah those are given by `FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "InformationHelpIcon"]` and `FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "InformationHelpIconHot"]`

Comment: What works for the i icon is`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "InformationHelpIcon"]/.GraphicsBox->Graphics`..

Comment: In general you'd use `FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "InformationHelpIcon"] // ToExpression` to convert boxes to a proper expression

Comment: you can also use `RawBoxes@FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "InformationHelpIcon"]`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the png files used as icons in menus:

```
files = FileNames["MenuItem*.png", $InstallationDirectory, ∞];

Grid[Partition[Flatten[{StringDrop[FileNameTake@#, -4], Import[#]} & /@ files],  6], 
  Dividers -> {{{True, False}}, All}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

In version 11.3 (Windows 10), these files are all in the directory:

```
DeleteDuplicates[DirectoryName /@ files]
```

[image]

***Note:*** Unicode character for circled information symbol:

```
"\:24D8"
```

> ```
> "ⓘ"
> ```

Comment: Note that some icons are missing, e.g., the ones for `\:f442` and `\:f443` as well as the one similar to ">".